# Python beautiful soup encoding

Tags: python, encoding, beautifulsoup

I have a problem with beautiful soup.
I try to ged rid of html tags in a string, therefore I have the following function

```
def cleanHtml(self, html):
    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html);
        content = soup.findAll(text=True)
        return ''.join(content);
    except:
        print html
```

when I now do:

```
print {'title' : string_with_german_umlauts}
print {'title' : self.cleanHtml(string_with_german_umlauts)}
```

I get the following output for the string 'Leder Gürtel' (meaning leather belt)

```
{'title': 'Leder G\xc3\xbcrtel'}
{'title': u'Leder G\xfcrtel'}
```

The right encoding is of course \xc3\xbc for the umlaut 'ü'.
After trying for the whole day to get this working, I'll give up and ask ;-)

I appreciate any help
Thx

Comment: In case this helps you: `'G\xc3\xbcrtel'` is a byte-string and `u'G\xfcrtel'` is a codepoint-string ("Unicode string") and is equivalent to `u'G\u00fcrtel'`.  `'G\xc3\xbcrtel'.decode('UTF-8')` returns `u'G\u00fcrtel'`.  While debugging consider at each step whether the data is in the form of bytes or codepoints, and when converting between one and the other, consider what encoding is being used.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you have umlauts in your result is expected behavior. Beautiful Soup handles unicode, so this is expected. What is the problem here? Is is that you are not seeing the umlaut in the dictionary? If so, that is not an issue at all, as the umlaut will be properly visible when you print:

```
>>> d = {'title': u'Leder G\xfcrtel'}
>>> for k in d:     
...     print k, d[k]
...
title Leder Gürtel
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm no expert on mongoDB, but you might want to mention that in your question, so that someone who /is/ well versed in mongo will pick up on that and help you out. Also, you don't mention what the actual problem is

Comment: I'm inserting the dict in my mongoDB. This is why I see the strange behaviour e.g. the 端 character (\u7aef) instead of an 'ü'.

Comment: thanks. But what kind of encoding is \u7aef? UTF-8 is \xc3\xbc.

Comment: Not quite sure what \u7aef is. Perhaps you're manipulating the string somewhere else - that could lead to a misinterpretation of what's going into mongo

Comment: yes I guess its definitely a python=>pymongo problem. Python itself handles the encoding correctly.